# What's wrong with this piece of scala code?

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet which can not be compiled:

```
val cids = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = Map.newBuilder[Int, Int]
for (c <- cids) {
  b += (c, c*2)
}
b.result()
```

Compiler reports that

```
console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (Int, Int)
               b += (c, c*2)
```

I have no idea what's the mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work:

```
for (c <- cids) {
   b += ((c, c*2))
}
```

The parenthesis are parsed by compiler as the argument-list parenthesis of the `+=` function, and not as a *tuple*. Adding nested parenthesis means a tuple is passed as the argument. It *is* confusing...

Comment: Is this mentioned in the specification? How is one supposed to know when it is interpreted as a tuple and when as an argument list?

Comment: It's so confusing, this answer is slightly wrong. It's not a parsing problem, but a problem with how the expression is typed.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov "auto-tupling" was never mentioned in the spec. There's an issue for that change, but I don't know offhand if it was ever added. "It's so confusing...", they want to get rid of it. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3583

Answer (score 5):

You can fix it the following way:

```
b += (c->c*2)
```

Comment: Or `b += (c, c*2).x`

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate question.

Normally, supplying an untupled arg list works as shown, but it doesn't work when the method is overloaded, because it will choose the method you didn't intend, and not bother to try auto-tupling your args.

```
scala> class C[A] { def f(a: A) = 42 }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C[(String, Int)]
c: C[(String, Int)] = C@3a022576

scala> c.f("1", 1)
res0: Int = 42

scala> class C[A] { def f(a: A) = 42 ; def f(a: A, b: A, rest: A*) = 17 }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C[(String, Int)]
c: C[(String, Int)] = C@f9cab00

scala> c.f("1", 1)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("1")
 required: (String, Int)
       c.f("1", 1)
           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using (immutable) values,

```
(cids zip cids.map(_ * 2)).toMap
```

Using `zip` we pair each value with its double, and the resulting list is converted to a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the documentation you will find : [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html)

The supported API is `ms += (k -> v)`  . That is you need to use

```
for (c <- cids) {
  b += (c -> c*2)
}
```

Alternately you could use the `((c, c*2))` syntax as suggested above. This is happening because the compiler has no way of knowing that the parentheses are for the tuple. It simply understands that argument as two parameters being passed to the += method.

Comment: That's not accurate, you _can_ add a tuple to a map. From the link you posted: "... Map("x" -> 24, "y" -> 25, "z" -> 26) means exactly the same as Map(("x", 24), ("y", 25), ("z", 26))" - the two are equivalent. In this specific instance, the compiler interpreted the parenthesis wrong because of the use of the `+=` _infix_ method; The problem was that id _didn't_ interpret `(c, c*2)` as a tuple.

Comment: @TzachZohar I don't think infix syntax is relevant. But the API in question is `mutable.Builder` per se. So the link is misleading.